# Resolving Artifacts using Jenkins job with the parent directory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am looking to download the artifacts using Jenkins job to resolve the artifacts from Artifactory. Specifying the file type and the path to the artifact works, However, unable to resolve all artifacts from the root directory.

Actual Artifactory Path:

```
repo_key:Group/Artifact/Version/path/to/artifact1/file.zip
repo_key:Group/Artifact/Version/path/to/artifact2/file.zip
```

Below Configuration in Jenkins job to Resolved Artifacts doesn't works:

```
repo_key:Group/Artifact/*=>Output
```

How do I download all files under the `Artifact` directory to the Output directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the format JBaruch mentioned *and* add the build metadata as matrix params, to support wildcard resolution for multiple files. 
For instance:

repo_key:Group/Artifact/**/***@publishing_build_name#LATEST**

Will get you the latest artifacts published by the job "publishing_build_name".

There's some helpful information and examples when clicking on the Question Mark next to the "Resolved Artifacts" field.

Answer (score -1):

`Artifact/*` will resolve files, directly located under `Artifact` directory (and there are none). What you need is `Artifact/**/*`.

Comment: `Artifact/**/*` gives a ERROR: Wildcard `'**'` is not allowed without matrix params for pattern `'repo_key:Group/Artifact/**/*'`